# Python: Script to check for login attempts and auto hard disk wipe out

Tags: python, security, cryptography

I am currently running on a linux server (*debian*) and I have encrypted my hard disk with `cryptsetup`.

In order to access to the hard disk, I would need to decrypt it with a password. However, in order to protect my hard disk in case it was being stolen, I would like to write a script that after the hacker fails to authenticate after 3 times (when password prompt for decrypting the hard disk), the python script will run and wipe out the hard disk.

*Is it possible to do that?*

The concern that I have is that the encryption key seems to be residing on the hard disk itself, thus, it does not give me any insurance that hacker might hack it using like maybe brute force or etc. So which is why is there a way to trigger a python script when it fails to login thrice?

Comment: *3 times* -- sheesh -- I hope that caps lock light shines bright.  But to your question, unless cryptsetup provides the ability to hook failed login attempts (they may, I have no idea), this seems difficult.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to use a reasonable password? If the "hacker" knows it, your scheme won't stop him, if he doesn't, he'll never decrypt the disk before the heat death of the universe (assuming that cryptsetup uses good encryption)...

Comment: What makes you think that "hackers" will use your login utility and not brute force on the disk itself?

Comment: Could be but it will be hard because it acts like bitlocker function, and the key will most likely be encrypted as well. I still not very sure about the cryptsetup architecture and first thing that comes to my mind is MDM function, whereby if the device is stolen, it will conduct a auto wipeout